# A circle is inscribed in a triangle; prove that a certain angle is bisected.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

My student showed me the following question.

A circle inscribed in triangle $ABC$ touches $AB$ at $D$, $BC$ at $E$, $AC$ at $F$. $G$ is on $DE$ such that $FG\perp DE$. Prove $FG$ bisects $\angle{AGC}$.

[image]

I managed to prove this using cartesian coordinates, but my proof takes about two pages of equations. I'm looking for a more elegant proof.

(Here is an outline of my proof. Let the circle have cartesian equation $x^2+y^2=1$ and assign coordinates: $D\space (-p,-\sqrt{1-p^2})$, $E\space (p,-\sqrt{1-p^2})$, $F\space (-q,\sqrt{1-q^2})$. In terms of $p$ and $q$, find the equations of the lines that make the three sides of the triangle, then find the coordinates of $A$, $C$ and $G$. Then show that the sum of gradients of $AG$ and $CG$ is $0$, so $FG$ bisects $\angle{AGC}$.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $O$ be the center of the incircle of $\triangle ABC$ and the circumcircle of $\triangle DEF$. Hence $OF\perp AC$, $\angle OAF=\frac{\angle A}{2}$ and $\angle OCF=\frac{180^{\circ}-\angle A-\angle B}{2}.$

Since $AD, AF$ are tangents and using [Alternate Segment Theorem](https://brilliant.org/wiki/alternate-segment-theorem-2/),
$$AD=AF=a~~\text{and}~~\angle ADF=\angle AFD=\angle FED=90-\frac{\angle{A}}{{2}}.$$
Using the same argument for the other tangents, it is easy to see that
$$CE=CF=c~~\text{and}~~\angle FEC=\angle EDF=\frac{\angle A+\angle B}{2}\implies \angle ADG=CEG.$$
Using the above facts,
$$\triangle AOF\sim \triangle FEG~~\text{and} ~~\triangle COF\sim\triangle FDG\implies \frac{a}{DG}=\frac{c}{GE}.$$
Therefore,
$$\triangle ADG\sim \triangle CEG\implies \angle CGE=\angle AGD\implies \angle AGF=\angle CGF.$$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Another approach:

Draw circumcircle of ABC. Extend GF to meet the circle at Y. Draw a tangent on inscribed circle, the tangent ppoint is X. As shown in figure:

$\widehat{OFC}=90^o$

$\widehat{OXY=90^o}$

therefore quadrilateral OFHX is an squar and $\widehat{FHX}=90^0$. XY and extension of GF meet at Y on circumcircle, this is only possible if XY is a dimeter of circumcicle and bisects AC and FG bisects angle AGC.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand the last part, "this is only possible if...". Perhaps you could elaborate?

Comment: @Dan, I am reffering to this theorem: in any triangle the bisector of angle A and the perpendicular bisector of a( the side opposite to angle A) meet at a point on the circumscribed circle.

Comment: I see. [Here](https://www.cuemath.com/ncert-solutions/prove-that-the-angle-bisector-of-any-angle-of-a-triangle-and-perpendicular-bisector-of-the-opposite-side-if-intersect-they-will-intersect-on-the-circumcircle-of-the-triangle/) is a proof of that theorem.